# How to mock different responses in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

in my test file I have:

```
describe('component', () => {
   globals.Globalfunct = {
    testfunc: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('something)
   }
   it('is a test', () => {

   })
   it('is another test', () => {
     // in here I want testfunc to return something else, how can I do this?
   })
}
```

I basically want the jest mock function `testFunc` to return something different every time. how can I do this?

I also cant get `mockImplementation` to work

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a different random string every time...

```
describe('component', () => {
   globals.Globalfunct = {
    testfunc: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('foo'),
   }

   beforeEach(() => {
      const randomStr = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      globals.Globalfunct.testfunc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(randomStr);
   });

   it('is a test', () => {

   })
   it('is another test', () => {
     // in here I want testfunc to return something else, how can I do this?
   })
});
```

## The explanation

When you have a `beforeEach` function in jest ([official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html#beforeeachfn-timeout)), it will call it before each test case. In the code above, it changes the mock function to another instance of the jest function before each of the tests, giving you a new, different answer every test case.